# Why is the default value for deferRender is set to false in jQuery data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just saw that 'Deferred rendering can be particularly useful when Ajax loading data as it allows DataTables to perform a number of performance enhancing optimisations and when deferred rendering is enabled, this can give a significant performance increase, since a lot less work is done at initialisation time.' Ultimately we all require best performance but it is noted that the default value is 'false' for deferRender option, Is there any significant issue or problem if it set as true? Or is there any other situations where this required?

Please comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender):

> Note that when enabled, it goes without saying that not all nodes will always be available in the table, so when working with API methods such as `columns().nodes()` you must take this into account.

My guess is that unless you're rendering a large data set, the performance benefit of setting `deferRender` to `true` is negligible. Setting it to `true` comes at the tradeoff of it being harder to use their other APIs, which is not desirable for most people.